# PHP addslashes to predefined set of characters

Tags: php, regex

How can I prepend certain characters with a backslash in a single function?

The equivalent of doing a bunch of `str_replace`s:

```
$text = "asdf[],.\?'";
$text = str_replace("'","\'", $text);
$text = str_replace("s","\s", $text);
$text = str_replace("[","\[", $text);
...etc...
```

I would like to pass in a character class like in regular expressions, but not sure how to have `preg_replace` prepend the backslash instead of replacing it.

```
$text = preg_replace("/['s\[]/","\{$var?}",$text);
```

I could set the characters in an array and loop through it, but I seem to remember a function that does just this.

Comment: BTW: Please note that `str_replace()` accepts `array` as arguments too

Answer (score 6):

Use [`addcslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php) if you want to escape single characters with a backslash:

```
$text = "asdf[],.\?'";
echo addcslashes($text, "'s[");
```

Output:

```
a\sdf\[],.\?\'
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/rMZyvM6q)

Answer (score 1):

Just add four backslashes in the replacement part,

```
<?php
$text = "asdf[],.\?'";
echo preg_replace("/(['s\[])/","\\\\$1",$text);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
a\sdf\[],.\?\'
```

Comment: Regex is a good option if you need to escape more complicated character sequences. For example, to escape `ba` as `\ba`. Regex shines here.